# Consumir WebService con Ionic

Tags: jquery, webservice, ionic

Por superación personal estoy aprendiendo Ionic, ya logré correr algunos ejemplos, pero donde no logro avanzar es consumir un WebService.

Regularmente con JQuery yo lo consumía de la siguiente forma:

```
 function obtenerProduccionFinca(inicioPeriodo, zona, finca, opcion, callbackFn) {
            var parametros = JSON.stringify({ 'inicioPeriodo': inicioPeriodo, 'zona': zona, 'finca': finca, 'opcion': opcion });
            $.ajax({
                url: '../../rrhh/ws/wsrrhh.asmx/obtenerProduccionFincaComparativo',
                type: 'POST',
                data: parametros,
                dataType: "text json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {
                    callbackFn(msg);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alertify.error('Ha ocurrido un error al contactar con el servidor');
                }
            });
        }
```

Ahora mi duda es como hacerlo con Ionic. Leí el tutorial alojado en https://blog.ng-classroom.com/blog/ionic2/rest-api-with-ionic/ pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

El primer error que me despliega es en el Home.ts que al importar el servicio me dice que no se encuentra el modulo.

```
import { UserService } from '../../providers/user-service';
```

[image: Error]

```
[ts] No se encuentra el módulo '../../providers/user-service'.
```

Y si intento correr el proyecto así, me despliega otro error:

```
C:\Users\ditzep\Desktop\Web\demo103>ionic serve
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729
--dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser - Ctrl+C to cancel
[15:33:49]  watch started ...
[15:33:49]  build dev started ...
[15:33:49]  clean started ...
[15:33:49]  clean finished in 3 ms
[15:33:49]  copy started ...
[15:33:49]  deeplinks started ...
Error: C:\Users\ditzep\Desktop\Web\demo103\src\pages\home\home.ts has a @IonicPage decorator,
but it does not have a corresponding "NgModule" at C:\Users\ditzep\Desktop\Web\demo103\src\pages\home\home.module.ts
    at new BuildError (C:\Users\ditzep\Desktop\Web\demo103\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at C:\Users\ditzep\Desktop\Web\demo103\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\deep-linking.js:57:21
    at <anonymous>
```

La estructura de mi proyecto es la siguiente:

[image: Estructura]

Y mis archivos son los siguientes.

User-service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserServiceProvider {

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello UserServiceProvider Provider');
  }
  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=25');
  }
}
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { UserService } from '../../providers/user-service';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  users: any[] = [];
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public userService: UserService) {

  }
  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.userService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(
      (data) => { // Success
        this.users = data['results'];
      },
      (error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      Demo 103
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img [src]="user.picture.medium">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>{{ user.name.first | uppercase }}</h2>
      <p>{{ user.email }}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { UserServiceProvider } from '../providers/user-service/user-service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    UserServiceProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Versiones instaladas:

ionic es 3.20.00
node.js  8.11.3
Angular  5.2.11

Les agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Ahora mismo no tengo tiempo para una respuesta útil (larga), pero por si te sirve de orientación, busca cómo se crea y cómo se usa un servicio en Angular, usando la clase HttpClient

Comment: Intente con un tutorial pero me despliega varios errores. Que lo logro manejar.